# Is it possible to access elements of a website?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a link here: https://fantasy.espn.com/football/players/add?leagueId=1589782588 and I've been wanted to pull data from it. In the developer console I typed out

```
let players = document.getElementsByClassName("AnchorLink link clr-link pointer")
players[0].text
```

and it works perfectly. How can I get this to work in my ide?

Comment: If you're not going via a legitimate API to get the desired data - but rather exploiting the raw HTML to get the desired - that's commonly referred as ***scraping***. It's not often legal, and it usually doesn't lasts long, since all it takes is for that website to slightly modify the selector hashes, modify the HTML, change the URL etc.

Answer (score 0):

***Disclaimer:*** the following is for **teaching purpose only** and should not be abused.
Use a public **API** *if* provided by the website owner.

---

Investigate what happens to the request by using the **Network tab**.
You'll notice that a **request** is made to an URI https://site.api.espn.com/apis/..... which ends in something like: `....ffl/news/players?days=30&playerId=2576623`.
If you click that link you'll go directly to a page that serves an API [response as JSON](https://site.api.espn.com/apis/fantasy/v2/games/ffl/news/players?days=30&playerId=2576623).

**Inspect** again the entire website <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + F</kbd> and look for that player ID `2576623` - and you'll notice that is stored inside each player image URI. So let's collect all those IDs.

Open Dev Tools **Console** and run:

```js
var _i = document.querySelectorAll("tbody .player__column img[src*='full/']");
console.log(_i);
```

Now that you have your image elements it's time to collect all the IDs:

```js
var _ids = [..._i].map(el => el.src.match(/(?<=full\/)[^\.]+(?=\.)/)[0]);
console.log(_ids)
```

From this point on you - can use any server-side script (or even JS if there's no ***CrossOrigin*** limitation), and fetch [that JSON data](https://site.api.espn.com/apis/fantasy/v2/games/ffl/news/players?days=30&playerId=2576623).